# Spring Security login issue when trying to access a url after authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-security-oauth2

I am learning spring security and has followed few tutorials on Youtube, I have completed the task as taught by the author/teacher but unfortunately i could not login when i try to access my urls for /user and /admin after login, though i receive granted authorities object from database with USER_USER and USER_ADMIN roles but still when i request those urls i throws exception for forbidden access, anyone can guide why this is happening?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    /*Authentication method*/
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("Admin").and().withUser("user").password("user").roles("User");
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    // Authorization - Should be from most secure to least one
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // To allow access to any url without permission is by using permitAll() method
        System.out.println("Accessign URL : ");
        http.authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("USER_ADMIN").
                antMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("USER_USER", "USER_ADMIN").
                antMatchers("/", "static/css", "static/js").
                permitAll().
                and().
                formLogin();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

MyUserDetails Class :

```
package com.springsecurity.demo.models;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3042145577630945747L;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorityList;

    public MyUserDetails() {
    }

    public MyUserDetails(User user) {
        this.userName = user.getUserName();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.authorityList = Arrays.stream(user.getUserRole().trim().split(",")).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println((this.authorityList.size() > 0 ? this.authorityList.get(0) : "Empty"));
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorityList;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

MyUserDetailsService class :

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public MyUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUserName(userName);

        user.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with name : " + userName));

        return user.map(MyUserDetails::new).get();
    }
}
```

UserRepository Class :

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    Optional<User> findByUserName(String userName);
}
```

Controller Class :

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String greet() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user")
    public String greetUser() {
        return ("<h1>Hello User!</h2");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
    public String greetAdmin() {
        return ("<h1>Hello Admin!</h2");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: try adding  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER_ADMIN')") to rest endpoint.

Comment: @dassum that didn't work too, i searched for this and found that i was doing a mistake in database user_role column by adding roles like USER_USER & USER_ADMIN, that unfortunately doesn't work, i found that you have to insert roles as Role_Admin and Role_User, that way it worked i don't know what's the logic behind this may be SimplegrantedAuthority or Authorities Class has to do something here..Thanks for the response though.

Comment: you should update the answer here. It might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with just updating my database user_roles column values from USER_USER & USER_ADMIN to ROLE_USER & ROLE_ADMIN it worked for me, I don't know exactly the reason but it was specified that SimpleGrantedAuthority class expects to have role names like Role_Admin & Role_User format and it worked perfectly for me.
Along with database change i updated my WebSecurity configure method to following,

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // To allow access to any url without permission is by using permitAll() method
        System.out.println("Accessign URL : ");
        http.authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers("/admin", "/api/v1/users").hasRole("ADMIN").
                antMatchers("/api/v1/students", "/api/v1/courses").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN").
                antMatchers("/", "static/css", "static/js").
                permitAll().
                and().
                formLogin();
    }
```